# Dependence on social opinion

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people do care about what the others think of them and some do not. Usually, the ones who don't care say that they "don't depend on social opinion" - they do whatever they want to do and act a way that may be not accepted by many people. And so, they say that the main mistake of the ones, who care is something like *Dependence on social opinion*.

Is there in English some special word or word combination for this "dependence"? Like "Social addiction" :D

**EDIT (CLARIFICATION)**
After reading comments I got, that maybe there is no special word for this situation.
Again, I'm not talking about disorder or abnormality - this is usual behaviour of most people. When we don't do something "stupid", because we think - "Omg, what will people think of me". We don't try to get to know a girl on the streen - "Omg, that's so stupid - if she refuses me, I'll look so stupid".
Usually, so-called PUA (pickup artists) use this word - "Guys, the main problem is that you do care what the others people think of you. You aren't free" - and so on. In Russian language there's no special word - just "social dependence". I thought, maybe there is some **special** word for the situation, but seems that I was wrong.

Comment: This is not a good answer so I am putting it in a comment.  It doesn't meet the OP requirement of an 'addiction' but I would describe someone like that as [gregarious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gregarious).

Comment: I have never heard anyone say "I don't depend on social opinion." This sentence doesn't really make sense. Most people would say instead that they "don't care what people think."

Comment: Does **social butterfly** mean what you are looking for?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're talking about, for example, a politician who says, "I base my opinions and positions on my own set of values; they don't change based on public opinion polls."  If so, I suggest that you [edit] your question to clarify it, and you might get better answers.

Comment: Since social media's so new, I'm going to venture a guess that there isn't any developed word for this - "social media addict" is probably the best you're going to get. But then again, urbandictionary never ceases to amaze when it comes to words for things like this...

Comment: Please clarify your question.  You gave as an example "social addict", but then said in a comment to an answer that you were not looking for a disorder.  Are you asking about the average person's responsiveness to peer pressure, or something more than that (e.g., how a crowd can turn into a mob) or what?

Comment: You may be looking for the word "conformity"

Comment: moonstar2001 is on the right track.  'Conformist' is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

One (extreme) variant is **histrionic personality disorder**.

> noun.
>   A personality disorder characterized by excessive emotionality and persistent attention-seeking behavior.

-- [The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.yourdictionary.com/histrionic-personality-disorder)

More details on [HPD at Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histrionic_personality_disorder) and the symptoms described by OP could be due to many other 
[disorders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_disorder).

Comment: I'm not looking for disorder. Just people, who don't care about what the others think, they claim, that this so-called 'dependence' is the main problem of people, who care.  Problem, but not disorder. This so-called dependence is normally accepted by many people - "Yes, I do care what the others think of me and I don't act like foolish idiot" "I've dropped ice cream on my pants - OMG, people around me probably thought of me as of idiot"